# How to swap values of two rows in Yii2 without violating unique constraint?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, transactions, yii2

I need somethink like

```
START TRANSACTION;
    UPDATE tasks 
    SET priority = 2 
    WHERE id = 1;

    UPDATE tasks 
    SET priority = 1 
    WHERE id = 2;
COMMIT;
```

when task1 haw priority 1, and task2 - 2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution in **MySQL**:

```
UPDATE tasks a
INNER JOIN tasks b on a.id <> b.id
SET a.priority = b.priority
WHERE a.id IN (1,2) 
      AND b.id IN (1,2)
```

I hope you can convert it into **ActiveRecord**.